# Can an informative predictor be correlated to an uninformative predictor?

Tags: correlation, predictive-models, predictor, noise

While reading the book [Applied Predictive Modelling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/), I stumbled over the following sentence (Page 202):

> For example, uninformative predictors with high correlations to
>   informative predictors had abnormally large importance values.

The context is trees and the procedure of getting the importance of predictors by analysing the splits of a tree. I understand that correlation between predictors can distort their perceived importance.

But, if two predictors are correlated, can one of them be informative and the other uninformative? What is the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trivial example, where an informative predictor $x$ has an additive uninformative component $u$ (that is, uninformative as long as $x$  is also in the model) and $u$ and $x$ are correlated.

```
. clear

. set obs 10000
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 10,000

. set seed 10011979

. gen u = rnormal()

. gen x = u + rnormal()

. gen y = 1 + 0*u + 3*x + rnormal()

. reg y x u

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =    10,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 9997)      =  92412.53
       Model |  184217.615         2  92108.8076   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  9964.14401     9,997  .996713415   R-squared       =    0.9487
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.9487
       Total |  194181.759     9,999  19.4201179   Root MSE        =    .99836

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   3.005743   .0098684   304.58   0.000     2.986399    3.025087
           u |  -.0044748   .0140715    -0.32   0.750    -.0320578    .0231082
       _cons |   1.006306    .009984   100.79   0.000      .986735    1.025876
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. corr u x
(obs=10,000)

             |        u        x
-------------+------------------
           u |   1.0000
           x |   0.7063   1.0000
```